# CSStickyHeaderFlowLayout swift

Tags: objective-c, iphone, swift, ios8, parallax

I'm trying to make parallax photo effect in my app using CSStickyHeaderFlowLayout
- https://github.com/jamztang/CSStickyHeaderFlowLayout/
and Swift language.

I have installed necessary Pod's file, add #import "CSStickyHeaderFlowLayout.h" to my "appName"-Bridging-Header.h file, and implemented this method:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

    var cell: UICollectionViewCell = UICollectionViewCell(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 400, 200));
    var imageView: UIImageView = UIImageView();
    var image: UIImage  = UIImage(named: "news2.jpg")!;
    imageView.image = image;
    cell.addSubview(imageView);
    return cell;

}
```

but now I have difficulties to translate this Obj-C code to Swift:

```
CSStickyHeaderFlowLayout *layout = (id)self.collectionViewLayout;
if ([layout isKindOfClass:[CSStickyHeaderFlowLayout class]]) {
    layout.parallaxHeaderReferenceSize = CGSizeMake(320, 200);
}
```

In my opinion after that step my effect should works. Am I right? Or I have missed something?

Thanks for help,
m.af

Comment: Why to use such a simple ObjC class in Swift. You can rewrite it or probably use my implementation: https://github.com/bernikovich/StickyHeaderFlowLayout

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do it like this in Swift

```
if let layout = self.collectionViewLayout as? CSStickyHeaderFlowLayout {
    layout.parallaxHeaderReferenceSize = CGSizeMake(320, 200)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
var layout = CSStickyHeaderFlowLayout()

if (layout.isKindOfClass(CSStickyHeaderFlowLayout.self)) {
    layout.parallaxHeaderReferenceSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, 426)

    layout.parallaxHeaderMinimumReferenceSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, 110)
    layout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, layout.itemSize.height)
    layout.parallaxHeaderAlwaysOnTop = true

    // If we want to disable the sticky header effect
    layout.disableStickyHeaders = true
}
```