# Slide UITableView up when scrolling starts

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

There is a particular element of the app I am developing at the moment that I am not sure of the best way to go about implementing.

Basically, I would like to have a view that has a `UITableView` about half way down the page. When the table view is scrolled down, the UITableView would start to slide up to the top of the page. Once it reaches that point, the table would just scroll as normal until the user scrolls back up (the table would slide back down to it's original position).

I managed to find an example of what I mean in the Spotify app. In a playlist, once you start scrolling, the whole able scrolls up. I'm pretty sure it's a feature in quite a few apps.

So like I say, I am just looking for some advice about the best way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know the Spotify app so maybe I don't get your question right but if you want to implement the behaviour like I think this library should do what you want:
[CSStickyHeaderFlowLayout](https://github.com/jamztang/CSStickyHeaderFlowLayout)

You should note that this library is made to be used with an `UICollectionView` and not an `UITableView` but I guess you could work with that.

**EDIT**

Also have a look at this SO Thread which deals with using this library in Swift code:
[csstickyheaderflowlayout-swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27046624/csstickyheaderflowlayout-swift)

Comment: You can use it via the Bridging Header

Comment: Also I found something concerning this library and swift here on stackoverflow, see my edited answer.

Comment: @user3746428 did you got it working or do you still need assistance ?

Comment: I ended up not implementing this feature, since I am very limited on time, but your suggestion seems to answer my question so I've marked it as accepted.